# Archimedean Property proof in the book of introduction to real analysis

Tags: analysis

Introduction to Real Analysis.page.42

> 2.4.3 Archimedean Property. If $x \in \mathbb R$, then there exists $ n_x \in \mathbb N $ such that $x \le n_x$.

$\quad$ Proof. If the assertion is false, then $n \le x$ for all $ n \in \mathbb N $ ; therefore, $x$ is an upper bound of $\mathbb N$.

My question is: If there does not exist $ n_x \in \mathbb N $ such that $x \le n_x$, then $n \lt x$, right? So why '' $n \le x$'' in the proof ?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I mean $$x<n \implies x \leq n$$ Probably the definition of upper bound used $\leq$ .

Comment: But if $n \lt x$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $x$ is also an upper bound of $\mathbb N$. As you say, maybe it's just for the defintion to use $ \le $

Comment: $n < x \implies n \le x$, so what they've said is obviously true, and $\forall n \in \Bbb N, n \le x$ is indeed the definition of "$x$ is an upper bound for $\Bbb N$", so they were just matching the exact definition. Your (Andrew Li's) statement that $n < x$ implies $x$ is an upper bound also requires the implicit realization that $n < x \implies n \le x$, just at a slightly different point.